# Recolor PDF to a single color

Tags: windows, windows-10, pdf

Is there any easy way to recolor PDF to a single color just like how we recolor images in MS PowerPoint so that i can take print out using only color ink.

Comment: Are you referring to greyscale?  Is the objective just to produce a printout or to create a new/modified PDF?  Are you using a color or monochrome printer (like a laser printer)?  Just FYI, if you have a color PDF and want to print it on a monochrome printer, you just need to print it (the printer driver will convert the colors).  The question says "print out using only color ink".  Is that a typo, or are you trying to print on a color printer with some missing colors?

Comment: I need to convert all colors in the PDF to a single color. Not monochrome.

Comment: It sounds like maybe an XY problem, in which case, there might be other avenues of solution.  But you can recolor a PDF in an image editor that opens PDFs, like Photoshop.  The specifics for the task would depend on exactly what you need to do.

Comment: If you need greyscale, you could open the PDF in a viewer and print it as grayscale to a PDF printer, which would produce a new PDF with all of the colors converted to greyscale.

Comment: I need all the colors converted to a color that i want.

Comment: In case you're not aware, if you plan to post a self-answered question, there's an "Answer your own question" checkbox at the bottom of the Ask Question page.  If you check that, it also opens an answer box on the same page.  You can then work on both until the pair is ready to go, then post them both at the same time.  That will save answering unnecessary questions while you're working on the answer.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 No, I never planned to post an answer. It is just a method that i tried and succeed. I need an easy way to recolor PDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same PowerPoint recolor option to recolor PDF.

**Step 1:**

Convert PDF to images using any of the online tools. Example [freepdfconvert](https://www.freepdfconvert.com)

**Step 2:**

After conversion download images to your computer.

**Step 3:**

Open Microsoft PowerPoint > Create a blank presentation

**Step 4:**

On the INSERT tab, in the Images group, click Pictures. Then insert downloaded images.

[image: Click Pictures]

**Step 5:**

Select the picture you want to recolor.

**Step 6:**

Under Picture Tools, on the Format tab, in the Adjust group, click Color and under recolor select any of the color option from 3rd row.

[image: Choose recolor]

**Step 6:**

Now right click on a picture and select Save as Picture option. Do the same for all your pictures.

**Step 7:**

Convert images to PDF using any of the online tools. Example [jpg2pdf](http://jpg2pdf.com/)

Comment: I'm still looking for an easier solution.

Comment: This tool is an easier solution because it does almost all of those steps for you: https://supertool.org/automatically-add-color-to-pdfs-to-print-without-black-ink/